# MVC knockout select tag value assignment

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to load a select tag from an ajax call.  I can get the select statement loaded, but when I try to assign the value it fails. Thanks for any help!

HTML Code

```
<select data-bind="value: state, options: allStates, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'abbreviation', optionsCaption:'Please pick a state...'" class="form-control" id="state" name="state"></select>'

var cSource = function (data) {
    var self = this;'
    self.state = ko.observable(data.state);
    self.allStates = ko.observableArray([]);

// get the list of states from the server
$.getJSON('@Url.Action( "AllStates", "Home" )', function(myData) {
    // myDate is a list of states
    self.allStates(myData);
});
```

[Not Assigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClCfz.jpg)

```
var modelData = @Html.Raw( Json.Encode( Model ) );  // does not contain a list of states
    mySource = new cSource(modelData); 
    ko.applyBindings(mySource);
```

C# Object

```
public static List<cStates> usStates()
 {
        List<cStates> myStates = new List<cStates>();
        myStates.Add( new cStates() { abbreviation = "AL", name = "ALABAMA" } );
        myStates.Add( new cStates() { abbreviation = "AK", name = "ALASKA" } );
        ....
        return myStates;
 }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult AllStates()
  {
        return Json( ChoiceProducts.States.BLL.cStates.usStates(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

If I load the states from a javascript json object it works.

```
var states = [{"name": "Alabama","abbreviation": "AL"},{"name": "Alaska",
    "abbreviation": "AK"},.....
self.state = ko.observable(data.state);
self.allStates = ko.observableArray(states);
```

[Properly Assigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wREP3.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to update the state in the ajax call?  Or are you saying that the value is never assigned on page load?

Comment: If fails how? Show us the error in the console

Comment: The value never gets assigned on page load. 
self.state = ko.observable(data.state);  // this line doesn't work

Comment: We will need some more code then.  Like what calls `cSource` and is `data` null or undefined?  Most likely either `data` or `data.state` is null on page load but without more code it is hard to say where and why.

Comment: I added the binding and some images. I hope this helps.

Comment: Is there code missing from your getJSON callback? Because the variable "states" is never defined in what you've posted.

Comment: I fixed the variable states - it should have been myData

Answer (score 0):

You need to use knockout's `ko.utils.arrayMap` for data from the server.  Before applying bindings do something like:

```
var mappedState = ko.utils.arrayMap(stateObjectFromServer, function(item) {
    return new State(item.name, item.abbreviation);
});
```

And here is a great resource to help with that:

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

Answer (score 0):

Controller, I added

```
ViewBag.myStates = ChoiceProducts.States.BLL.cStates.usStates();
```

HTML, I added

```
self.allStates = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw( Json.Encode( ViewBag.myStates ) ));
```

And it worked. I didn't have to do a separate ajax call that way.